# CSS Problems with increasing menu height on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu that increases in height and displays a vertical list when you hover over it. If there is a way to make a smooth transition when the menu increases in height that would be nice too.

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #989898;
}
#nav:hover {
  height: 80px;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}
#nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a gif demonstration of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Look into CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example: its similar to what u want...

**[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659814/css-nested-list-menu-hover-problem)**

Comment: Thanks vishalkin! This really helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I added this code to yours to make it animate:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/7HS8p/

Comment: I liked yours better than mine because of the 'hover-off' effect.. it slides back up, unlike mine. 1+

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[**jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZLwt/4/)

```
-webkit-animation: move .5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

@-webkit-keyframes "move" {
 100% {
   height:80px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Exactly like that! Thanks Josh C :)